# Hide selected value of Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uipickerview, picker

I have a Picker within a Form but I want to show the selected value of the Picker only in another TextField within this Form and not in the Picker.

[image: Hide selected value in Picker]

Is there a possibility to hide the selected value in a Picker?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a `Picker` but you could use `NavigationLink` as a work-around:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var input = ""
    @State private var active = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink("Select", isActive: $active) {
                    List {
                        Button("Item 1") {
                            input = "Item 1"
                            active = false
                        }
                        Button("Item 2") {
                            input = "Item 2"
                            active = false
                        }
                        Button("Item 3") {
                            input = "Item 3"
                            active = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                TextField("", text: $input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```